# Xively Android client Service crashes

Tags: android, xively

I am exploring Xively Framework using Android client.
I have installed "service" given in Demo application.
When I start app on Android 2.3 and 4.0 device it is crashing  .
Below is stack track for the same.Surprisingly it is working on Android 4.1.
Any suggestion what need to done do make it work on Android 2.3 and 4.0 devices

Stacktrace
10-25 18:25:18.854: D/HttpService(17080): onCreate()
10-25 18:25:18.874: W/dalvikvm(17080): Exception Ljava/lang/RuntimeException; thrown while initializing Landroid/os/AsyncTask;
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    at com.xively.android.service.HttpService.executeRequest(HttpService.java:276)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    at com.xively.android.service.HttpService.put(HttpService.java:235)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    at com.xively.android.service.HttpService.access$1(HttpService.java:232)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    at com.xively.android.service.HttpService$1.updateFeed(HttpService.java:73)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    at com.xively.android.service.IHttpService$Stub.onTransact(IHttpService.java:77)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.(AsyncTask.java:607)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.(AsyncTask.java:607)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    at android.os.AsyncTask.(AsyncTask.java:190)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/JavaBinder(17080):    ... 7 more
10-25 18:25:18.884: W/dalvikvm(17080): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c2e1f8)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080): FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder Thread #1
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    at com.xively.android.service.HttpService.executeRequest(HttpService.java:276)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    at com.xively.android.service.HttpService.put(HttpService.java:235)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    at com.xively.android.service.HttpService.access$1(HttpService.java:232)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    at com.xively.android.service.HttpService$1.updateFeed(HttpService.java:73)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    at com.xively.android.service.IHttpService$Stub.onTransact(IHttpService.java:77)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.(AsyncTask.java:607)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.(AsyncTask.java:607)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    at android.os.AsyncTask.(AsyncTask.java:190)
10-25 18:25:18.884: E/AndroidRuntime(17080):    ... 7 more

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue wit the Android library. There is an open issue in Github. The team is working on testing a fix but basically it is a user contributed library that is highly unstable.

You are best off using [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) and performing the API functions from there. This will allow you to use Xively with Android.